I'm getting Could not parse CloudFormation template for the following serverless.yml
The Serverless configuration file builds successfully, but deployment fails despite the IAM policy having full permissions. The logs indicate progress only up to the message: "Deployment bucket not found. Updating stack to include deployment bucket definition. Ensuring that deployment bucket exists." This issue arises when attempting to run the serverless deploy command.
useDotenv: true

service: ${env:NAME}
plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-webpack

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: ap-south-1
  versionFunctions: false

resources:
  Resources:
    lambdaCogRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: ${env:NAME}-${env:STAGE}-lambda-ddb-role
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: 
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: 
                - sts:AssumeRole
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - !GetAtt lambdaCognitoAdminGetUserPolicy

    lambdaCognitoAdminGetUserPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogGroup
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
              Resource:
                - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*"
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - cognito-idp:AdminGetUser
                - cognito-idp:AdminSetUserMFAPreference
                - cognito-idp:ListUsers
                - cognito-idp:AdminLinkProviderForUser
                - cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes
                - cognito-idp:InvokeFunction
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:cognito-idp:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:userpool/${CognitoUserPool}"

    CognitoUserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: ${env:NAME}-${env:STAGE}-user-pool
        AutoVerifiedAttributes:
          - email
        UsernameConfiguration:
          CaseSensitive: true
        MfaConfiguration: OFF
        UsernameAttributes:
          - email
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 8
            RequireLowercase: true
            RequireNumbers: true
            RequireSymbols: true
            RequireUppercase: true
        Schema:
          - Name: email
            AttributeDataType: String
            Mutable: false
            Required: true

    CognitoUserPoolClient:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
      Properties:
        ClientName: ${env:NAME}-${env:STAGE}-user-pool-client
        GenerateSecret: false
        SupportedIdentityProviders:
          - Google
          - COGNITO
        CallbackURLs:
          - ${env:CALLBACK_URL}
        LogoutURLs:
          - ${env:LOGOUT_URL}
        AllowedOAuthFlows:
          - implicit
        AllowedOAuthScopes:
          - email
          - openid
          - aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
          - profile
          - phone
        ExplicitAuthFlows:
          - ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
          - ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
        AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true
        UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool

    CognitoUserPoolDomain:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain
      Properties:
        Domain: ${env:NAME}-${env:STAGE}
        UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool

  Outputs:
    MyAppUserPoolId:
      Description: The Id of the Cognito User Pool
      Value: !Ref CognitoUserPool
    MyAppUserPoolClientId:
      Description: The Id of the User Pool Client
      Value: !Ref CognitoUserPoolClient

functions:
  forgotPassword:
    handler: functions/forgotPassword/index.handler
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          trigger: CustomMessage
          pool: ${env:NAME}-${env:STAGE}-user-pool
          existing: true
    environment:
      COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID: !Ref CognitoUserPool

  postConfirmation:
    handler: functions/postConfirmation/index.handler
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          trigger: PostConfirmation
          pool: ${env:NAME}-${env:STAGE}-user-pool
          existing: true
    environment:
      COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID: !Ref CognitoUserPool

  resendCode:
    handler: functions/resendCode/index.handler
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          trigger: CustomMessage
          pool: ${env:NAME}-${env:STAGE}-user-pool
          existing: true
    environment:
      COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID: !Ref CognitoUserPool

  signUp:
    handler: functions/signUp/index.handler
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          trigger: CustomMessage
          pool: ${env:NAME}-${env:STAGE}-user-pool
          existing: true
    environment:
      COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID: !Ref CognitoUserPool

custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules: true
    excludeFiles: ./**/*.test.js

  dotenv:
    path: .env


Try to add the bucket in the provider block, an existing bucket:
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: ap-south-1
  deploymentBucket:
    name: my-custom-deployment-bucket #Update this with your bucket name
    blockPublicAccess: true

The deployment bucket must reside in the same region as the resources being deployed.
